# iPhone: add navigation bar to tableview subclass

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My view controller will open modal view that is a UITableView subclass. UITableView subclass dont have navigation bar. So how can I add it programmatically ? Because I need cancel button on it to close this modal view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a table view controller to a navigation controller, and present the navigation controller modally.  For example (this is all pseudo-code as I'm not sure of the exact method names):

```
MyTableViewController *tvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
tvc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" target:self action:@selector(dismissModalViewController)];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc]];
[self presentModalViewController:navController];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to push the view with a navigation bar and back button and you are using a TableView controller, then why not just use a NavigationController to push it since this will give you the navigation bar and back button by default?

Comment: Im push it with my navigation controller, but there is no navigation bat at my table view subclass

Comment: Maybe because i'm using UITableview subclass instead of UIViewController

Comment: the answer of the person above me will work, it depends on whether you want the navigation bar in the first view controller or not. If you don't then use his option above and push the nav controller modally. If you want to have the bar in both views then use a navigation controller with the first view already pushed on and then when appropriate push the table view controller. In this case though you are not doing it modally, modal view controller pushing is to have an independent view slide up over your current view completely.